# Use jdbcPollingChannelAdapter to perform multiple queries

Tags: spring-integration

I am new to spring integration, I have requirements similar to the below, data is being read from multiple tables. I am trying to implement jdbcpollingchanneladapter and jdbcMessageHandler, can anyone help with an example using java DSL?

Read the list of people
For each person get a list of departments
For each department get a list of managers
For each manager get the list of people
b. process the people information
c. write the information into a csv

I am using MessageSource to before DB queries and mapping result values to POJO by using a Mapper.  How do I use the results as lookup values to perform another query.

```
@EnableIntegration
public class IntegrationConfig {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel FamilyChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "FamilyChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000"))
    public MessageSource<Object> familyNumberMessageSource() {
        JdbcPollingChannelAdapter jdbcPollingChannelAdapter = new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(dataSource, NCFBulkOrderQuery.SELECT_NCF_BULK_ORDER_DATE);
        return jdbcPollingChannelAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageHandler familyNumberHandler(){
        JdbcMessageHandler jdbcMessageHandler = new JdbcMessageHandler(dataSource, NCFBulkOrderQuery.SELECT_NCF_BULK_ORDER_DATE);
        return jdbcMessageHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow jdbFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("FamilyChannel")
                .handle(familyNumberMessageSource(), "receive")
                .get();

    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply construct a SQL statement with JOINs etc to fetch everything in one query?

Comment: @GaryRussell, I think writing one query would work and I would use spring batch.  I choose spring integration because with spring batch each step in independent and from what I read spring integration should be able to read from multiple tables, plus I would like to gain a better understanding of how spring integration works.

Comment: Would you mind to elaborate more what does that *read from multiple tables* mean? Not clear why single query is not considered as a read from several tables...

Comment: It's more efficient to do it in SQL rather than multiple queries. If you really want to do it, you can use a series of JDBC outbound gateways for the subsequent queries.

Comment: @ArtemBilan When reading from multiple tables output from one table becomes input for the next one.  I thought it would have been easier to transform the data utitlizing spring integration components instead of using one query.

Comment: Well, that's not I have in mind about multiple tables... It is exactly about what Gary explain with a single JOIN query. Much efficient and not so bad for reading and transforming, especially when you don't need intermediate objects. Of course Spring Integration can do for you multi queries as Gary shows with a bunch of `JDBC outbound gateways`.

Comment: Thanks for your help @GaryRussell